# TYPO3 9.5.21 startpage /index/ in URI

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I've updated TYPO3 from 8.x to 9.5.21 and the page is available like this `http://example.com`

But if I go back to the startpage it always appends `/index/` and then the URI looks like this `http://example.com/index/`.

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was the default: / in the routeEnhancers.

```
routeEnhancers:
  PageTypeSuffix:
    type: PageType
    default: /
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your startpage the root page? You can check that in the page properties => Tab "Behaviour" => Use as Root Page

And you should check the URL Segment field in your page properties. If your start page is your root page, the field should be empty.

Another thing to check is the routing configuration in your site config. You can find it in `config/sites/`. Do you have a special setting in the `routeEnhancers` section?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Yes it is the root page and the URL Segment is / if i clear the field it becomes an / again.
This is the routeEnhancer int the config.yaml:

routeEnhancers:
  PageTypeSuffix:
    type: PageType
    default: /
    map:
      /: 0
      feed.rss: 9818
      sitemap.xml: 1533906435
routes:
  -
    route: robots.txt
    type: staticText
    content: "User-agent: *\r\nDisallow: /typo3/\r\nDisallow: /typo3_src/\r\nAllow: /typo3/sysext/frontend/Resources/Public/*"